# VBScript: I need to be able to read all the subkey names in a registry key and check for a dword value in each

Tags: vbscript

I am stumped here. I can't seem to wrap my head around getting the subkeys read into an array, and then walk through each subkey to search for a certain Dword value. I could assign variables to every subkey (which would take forever.)

My script works fine when I have it set up to look at one subkey and one value:

```
Const HKLM = &H80000002
Const REG_SZ        = 1
Const REG_EXPAND_SZ = 2
Const REG_BINARY    = 3
Const REG_DWORD     = 4
Const REG_MULTI_SZ  = 7


strKeyPath = "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Program\Policies\policy1"
strValueName = "lastStatus"

Set objRegistry = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")

objRegistry.GetDWORDValue HKLM,strKeyPath,strValueName,dwValue

If dwValue = 0 Then
Wscript.Echo strcomputer & " not done."

Elseif dwvalue = 3 Then
Wscript.Echo strcomputer & " is done!"
```

But, I need the script to walk through HKLM\Software\program\policies\policy1, then HKLM\Software\program\policies\policy2, then HKLM\Software\program\policies\policy3... until it reads every policy, of which there are 32 to 34 depending on the computer.

Then I need to check within each policy subkey if a dword value = 0 or 3.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you mean by "can't wrap my head around arrays". Do you mean you don't like the idea? In that case if you can be sure about the names of the subkeys you can do it like

```
For i = 1 To 34
    strKeyPath = "SOFTWARE\Program\Policies\policy" & i
    objRegistry.GetDWORDValue HKLM,strKeyPath,strValueName,dwValue
Next
```

If you just mean you don't know the proper way to do it, the normal approach would be

```
Const HKLM = &H80000002
strComputer = "."
strKeyPath = "SOFTWARE\Policies\"
strValueName = "lastStatus"

Set objRegistry = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")

objRegistry.EnumKey HKLM, strKeyPath, subKeys

For Each subKey In subKeys 
    objRegistry.GetDWORDValue HKLM,strKeyPath & subKey ,strValueName,dwValue
Next
```

Please note that either way, if you use the WMI registry provider the keyPaths are always without "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\" because you have (correctly) specified that as constant already.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I just meant that I was having trouble understanding how arrays work with enumerating keys. This helps though. I think I will try it the conventional way. The policy keys are actually complicated GUIDs, i just wrote it that was for the sake of simplicity, so I don't think that first approach would work.